# Check if my array contains a dictionary

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an array that contains a mixture of strings, arrays, and dictionaries. I would like to check if it contains a dictionary. I am trying the following, but receiving errors:

```
if array.contains(Dictionary<String, AnyObject>) {

 }
```

How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to bother with overloading the `contains` method if you don't want to – there's already a [version of it that can take a custom predicate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_SequenceType_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/intfm/SequenceType/s:FEsPs12SequenceType8containsFzFzWx9Generator7Element_SbSb) to check against each element to determine whether it should be considered to be 'in the array'.

It has the advantage of returning early as soon as it finds a match, unlike `filter`. You could still turn this into an extension method if you really want – but in my opinion it's so concise you shouldn't have to.

```
if array.contains({$0 is [String:AnyObject]}) {
    print("contains dictionary")
} else {
    print("doesn't contain dictionary")
}
```

Comment: Good catch, I missed it when I was typing up my answer. That's what I get for StackOverflowing late at night!

Comment: @ColGraff It's okay, we've all been there! ;)

Answer (score 3):

@Ryan, the type does not have to conform to the `Equatable` protocol.

This would get the job done:

```
extension Array {

    // This is a concise, yet inefficient implementation
    func contains<T>(type type : T.Type) -> Bool {
        return !filter({ $0 is T }).isEmpty
    }

    // Here is a more efficient implementation
    func contains<T>(type type : T.Type) -> Bool {
        var contains = false
        for element in self {
            if element is T {
                contains = true
                break
            }
        }
        return contains
    }
}
```

It can be used as such:

```
if array.contains(type: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>.self) {
    // Run code if the array holds a dictionary of the given type
}
```

Comment: Looks good. The only concern is that `filter` will iterate completely through the `Array` and won't abort if a match is found early. This could be problem with a very large `Array`.

Comment: Yes I considered that. I just wanted it to look clean :)
I will update my answer with a more efficient version.

Comment: @AdamH. You actually don't need to use `filter` or iterate through the array yourself – `contains` can take a custom predicate in order to check against each element, and will return early if a match is found. I have given an example of this in [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37359989/2976878).

Comment: Yes I apologize. I deleted my comment after reading over that.

Comment: @AdamH. No problem :) I deleted my comment too.

Answer (score 0):

This requires that the array elements conform to the Equatable protocol (which Dictionary doesn't).

You would have to extend contains with something like this:

```
extension Array {
    func contains<T where T : Equatable>(obj: T) -> Bool {
        return self.filter({$0 as? T == obj}).count > 0
    }
}
```